# How can I use sonarqube in windows 10 without a docker (or any other) container to analyze Node apps?

Tags: sonarqube

The question says it all.

Running Windows 10 (home) and googling for the past two hours on running SonarQube in windows10. Everything I came cross talks about running SonarQube in docker.

Anyone out here know if it's even possible to run SonarQube in windows without a container. If it is, how do I do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like I can run the server with  a Java 11 install.

Once I did that the docs led the way.

Comment: Could you add any details of how you did this?